# Is there a way to make a design like this, and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have been having a hard time making a header for a website I am working on. I have been trying to make the design below:

[image]

The part that is crippling me is I do not know how to make something like this responsive. The pointy part on the blue section needs to stay the way it is, but have the rest of the header stretch to the right side. I don't know *all* the ins and outs of css, and I've been looking for something like this but failed to find a post close to this.

***EDIT: The most critical part of this, is that the white part in between the logo div and menu bar, needs to be transparent. It would have been so easy if It could have only been a solid color, but it needs to be able to show the background image behind the header :/

Comment: add your code segment for more understandable

Comment: Have you considerd using a background image for the non-blue part of the bar?

Comment: I would suggest to create each element first like the button and the vertical bar with the links before you position them according to your design. Additionaly, read how css `media queries` work.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a header, a link for the logo, a nav bar, and put the links in the nav bar. I would add a media query to set the min width to fit all the links, and collapse them at the width breakpoint:

```
body {
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
a.logo {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 24px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: black;
}
nav {
  position:relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height:24px;
  width:100%;
  background: black;
  text-align: left
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  nav a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```
<header>
  <a class="logo">#</a>
  <nav>
    <a>#</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The keys to responsiveness in this example:

- media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries
- percents

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by using media queries and bootstrap 4.0 version as there are many classes which help you to achieve this. For example "ml-auto" class will push your element extreme right as it value is defined "margin-left:auto!important" in bootstrap. There are plenty of classes you play around. As per your design I have provided solution. I have created it using Bootstrap version 4 and it is responsive in mobile, tablet and desktop. If you want you can write your classes too. Please try below code and check working snippet:

```css
#nav-header {
            position: relative;
        }

        #nav-header:before {
            content:"";
            width: 80px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background:#fff;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        #nav-header .navbar-brand {
            background:#fe0000;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            color:#fff;
            text-align:center;
            border-radius: 100px;
            border: 10px solid #fff;
            z-index: 4;
        }

        @media (min-width: 320px) {
            #nav-header .navbar-brand {
                padding: 2% 10%;                
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {

            #nav-header {
                margin: 25px 0 25px 25px;
            }

            #nav-header .navbar-brand {
                padding: 1.5% 8%;
            }

        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            #nav-header .navbar-brand {
                padding: 1.4% 6%;                
            }
        }



         #nav-header, #navbarSupportedContent {
            background: #003cff;
            padding:0;
         }

         #navbarSupportedContent {
            z-index: 9;
         }

         #nav-header .navbar-nav {
            list-style: initial;
            color: #fff;
         }

         #nav-header .navbar-nav li {
            margin-right: 2em;
            margin-left: 2em;
         }

         #nav-header .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color:#fff; 
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;           
         }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="nav-header" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Option 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```